# How to log application message using NXLog

Tags: java, spring-boot, nxlog

I am trying to log an application information using NXLog. Actually i am developing a RESTful web services in Spring Boot and using windows platform, i need to log messages using NXLog so that my client will take the logs from NXLog and display it. I am new to NXLog, could someone else help me in sorting out this problem

NOTE: My logs will be in JSON format